# Initialization of a C-styled array (to the value 1) who's size is a template parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
// sz can only be 3 or 4
template<int sz>
void func() {
 int arr[sz]; 
}
```

I would like to initialize `arr` to be all ones without a loop. Is this possible to do?
I'm envisioning something like

```
int arr[sz] = {1, 1, 1,...,1};
```

but for a variable sized array.

I think one approach is

```
int arr[sz] = (sz == 4) ? {1, 1, 1, 1} : {1, 1, 1};
```

Comment: Why not just use `std::array`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Woudn't I run into the same issue? I don't think there's a constructor for `std::array` that fills the array to a constant value

Comment: While there is no way that I know of to accomplish this at construction, `std::array` does have a `fill` function that can be called after the array is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler if you use `std::array`, i.e. you can use the immediately invoke lambda to return the corresponding array based on the value of `sz`

```
// sz can only be 3 or 4
template<int sz>
void func() {
  std::array<int, sz> arr = []() -> std::array<int, sz> {
    if constexpr (sz == 4) 
      return {1, 1, 1, 1};
    else
      return {1, 1, 1};
  }();
}
```

Since C++17 guarantees copy elision, copy/move construction is not involved here.

---

C++14 solution

```
std::array<int, 3> 
gen_arr(std::integral_constant<int, 3>) {
  return {1, 1, 1};
}

std::array<int, 4> 
gen_arr(std::integral_constant<int, 4>) {
  return {1, 1, 1, 1};
}

// sz can only be 3 or 4
template<int sz>
void func() {
  std::array<int, sz> arr = gen_arr(std::integral_constant<int, sz>{});
}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding `static_assert(sz == 3 || sz == 4, "sz must be 3 or 4");` above the `if`.

Comment: Is the `if constexpr` needed? We can't currently compile with C++17, only 14 or earlier

Comment: @RemyLebeau If we explicitly instantiate the templates for `sz=3,4`, would that remove the need to `static_assert`?

Comment: @24n8 The `static_assert` just helps to ensure you can't ever instantiate the template with other unsupported values. In C++14 and earlier, you can use SFINAE (ie, `std::enable_if`) or template specialization to achieve a similar result as the `if constexpr`, but it will require more code, as you will have to duplicate the code for each value of `sz`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I understand what the `static_assert` does, but I was under the impression that if you explicitly instantiate templates (e.g., in this case we'd explicitly instantiate for `sz == 3` and `sz = =4`), then if someone tries to instantiate for some other `sz` value, the linker will complain? Is this understanding wrong? If it's correct, then it seems the `static_assert` won't be needed?

Comment: "*then if someone tries to instantiate for some other sz value, the linker will complain*" It depends. In my previous example, if you specified `sz` as 2, the compiler would complain that `{1, 1, 1}` could not be converted to `array<int, 2>`. And in the C++14 example, the compiler will complain that it can't find a matching function. None of which are as user-friendly as `static_assert` with a *clear* error message.

Comment: @24n8 The C++17 solution presented allows any value of `sz`, but only 3 and 4 will initialize the array correctly. Values greater than 4 will fill the array wilth zeros, and values less than 3 will fail to compile (not link) due to too many initializers. The C++14 solution doesn't suffer from that, it will just fail to compile (unknown function) for values other than 3 and 4. The`static_assert` lets you provide your own meaningful error message.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions work great and the suggestion of using `std::array` is definitely the best idea. If you want to allow more options you could revert to variadic templates:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto ones_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::array<int, sizeof...(I)>{ (I, 1)... };
}
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto ones() {
    return ones_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<int sz>
void func() {
    auto arr = ones<sz>();

    copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "funct<3>(): ";
    func<3>();
    std::cout << "funct<4>(): ";
    func<4>();
    std::cout << "funct<7>(): ";
    func<7>();
}
```

Due credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41660210/6070341).