# How have the semantics of prvalues and glvalues changed in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

[This](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html) page on the language differences between C++17 and C++14 states that

> The meaning of prvalue and glvalue has been revised, prvalues are no
>   longer objects, but merely “initialization”.

I understand this has something to do with mandatory copy elision. My question is: precisely how have the semantics of prvalues and glvalues changed?

Comment: They've changed in whatever ways were necessary for [guaranteed elision to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work).

Comment: @NicolBolas are you saying the question is a dupplicate?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: I'm saying it could be. I wasn't certain enough to dupe-hammer it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, that's the sole purpose for which they have changed. Am I wrong? In this case, that's a dup. The fact that the titles differ doesn't make it a different question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does guaranteed copy elision work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work)