# Copying parameter invokes deleted constructor when that constructor shouldn't be called

Tags: c++, c++14, move, c++17, deleted-functions

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper() = delete;
    Wrapper(const Wrapper&) = delete;
    Wrapper(Wrapper&&) = delete;

    ~Wrapper() = default;

    Wrapper(const T&) = delete;
    Wrapper(T&& in) : instance{std::move(in)} {}

    T instance;
};

void foo(Wrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>>) {}

int main() {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    foo(std::move(ptr));
}
```

This has been working in C++17 so I never gave it thought but why does this code try and invoke the move constructor in C++14?  Shouldn't it be constructed in place in the function argument?  This seems to not be a problem with c++17 but is not compiling with c++14.

The only workaround I see is to make the `foo` parameter an rvalue, but is there anything I can do to make this work without making the parameter in `foo` an rvalue in C++14?

---

My first thought would be that a temporary would have to be constructor in order to be passed to the function but what is even more surprising is that even with `-fno-elide-constructors` and undeleting the move constructors and copy constructors those do not seem to be called!  Is this a bug in gcc and clang both?

See https://wandbox.org/permlink/f6sa5Rm3NxZLy5P1 for the error
And see for the strange behavior https://wandbox.org/permlink/Kh6CG4OVbUAjvEZz

Comment: what are the exact errors you get

Comment: @vu1p3n0x posted them in the question, it was in the title as well

Comment: In your link for "see for the strange behavior" it does call move constructor

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I got confused.. Thought the print statement was in the wrong place.  Nvm the question was folly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `foo(std::move(ptr));` you are not giving it a `Wrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>>`.  So, the compiler generates a temporary and uses that to construct `foo`'s parameter.  Now, this can be elided out and we can directly construct a `Wrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>>` but the move/copy constructor still needs to be accessible, even if it is never called.

With C++17 this no longer happens.  We have [guaranteed copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work) which means no temporary is ever materialized and instead the parameter is directly constructed.

Comment: But then why is the move constructor never called?  Even with `-fno-elide-constructors`

Comment: @Curious cosntructor required by language but call can be eliminated by optimization.

Comment: @Curious Because even though the compiler is smart enough not to make a temporary the language standard says the appropriate constructor must still be accessible.

Comment: @Slava the `-fno-elide-constructors` suppresses that optimization

Comment: @NathanOliver then is the codepath followed after passing the flag that is meant to suppress elision buggy?  Because move elision should not be happening when that flag is passed

Comment: @Curious Not sure.  It calls the move constructor [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d24c421f3d00c937)

Comment: Very strange, thanks for the answer and that link!  But I will wait for an answer that addresses that since that is the main confusing issue for me here

Comment: @Curious Even your example link prints the move constructor so I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: @NathanOliver got confused.. I thought I had a print statement in the wrong place, nvm the question was folly...