# How to access a vector inside a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a vector of vectors type double. I basically need to be able to set 360 numbers to cosY, and then put those 360 numbers into cosineY[0], then get another 360 numbers that are calculated with a different a now, and put them into cosineY[1].Technically my vector is going to be cosineYa I then need to be able to take out just cosY for a that I specify...

My code is saying this:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++)
{
   for int n=0; n <= 360; n++
   {
      cosY[n] = cos(a*vectorOfY[n]);
   }
   cosineY.push_back(cosY);
 }
```

which I hope is the correct way of actually setting it.

But then I need to take cosY for a that I specify, and calculate another another 360 vector, which will be stored in another vector again as a vector of vectors.

Right now I've got:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++
{
    for (int n = 0; n <= 360; n++)
    {
       cosProductPt[n] = (VectorOfY[n]*cosY[n]);
    }
    CosProductY.push_back(cosProductPt);
 }
```

The VectorOfY is besically the amplitude of an input wave. What I am doing is trying to create a cosine wave with different frequencies (a). I am then calculation the product of the input and cosine wave at each frequency. I need to be able to access these 360 points for each frequency later on in the program, and right now also I need to calculate the addition of all elements in cosProductPt, for every frequency (stored in cosProductY), and store it in a vector dotProductCos[a].

I've been trying to work it out but I don't know how to access all the elements in a vector of vectors to add them. I've been trying to do this for the whole day without any results. Right now I know so little that I don't even know how I would display or access a vector inside a vector, but I need to use that access point for the addition.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By vector of vectors you mean..........a matrix? Your question is too long, and it is not clear what the specific issue here is.

Comment: I've tried the following now: cosProductPt[n] = (VectorOfY[n]*CosineY[a][n]); instead, but it didn't work.

Comment: jafergas I am definitely struggling to get my head around it, which is why it is hard for me to even explain it... I besically want to know how to access a vector inside the vector... My vector cosineY has a vector cosY inside it, I need to calculate cosProductPt by using cosY, where cosineY[0], and then store that in another vector that is storing this vector, CosProductY[0].

Comment: @Lukali C++ isn't a language you can actually learn through trial and error. I'd recommend you to read [one of these books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242) or at least check the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: You claim you have, but you don’t bother to show the definition.

Comment: @Lukali _"My vector cosineY has a vector cosY inside it ..."_ you cannot have a named variable inside a vector. What you probably want to have is a `std::vector<std::vector<double>> cosineY;`.

Comment: Definitely read up on `std::vector` [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and I would recommend incrementing using `< vec.size()` instead of a hard-coded number even if the size is known.  I also get nervous when I see `<=` as the exit condition of your inner loop.

Comment: I used radians yes. Alrite forget everything, just the first code that I given, where I push back cosY, it doesn't work. The result of 0*anything should be 0, and cos(0) is 1. Now I ain't getting 1 always when I read using a for loop. I am getting many many 0s and some 1s instead, where is my problem? I believe i figured out how to actually store and see now, but i am not getting the right output...

Comment: Thank you for help everyone, I have figured out where my problem lays. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++)
{
   for int n=0; n < 360; n++) // note traded in <= for <. I think you had an off by one 
                              // error here.
   {
      cosY[n] = cos(a*vectorOfY[n]);
   }
   cosineY.push_back(cosY);
 }
```

Is sound so long as `cosY` has been pre-allocated to contain at least 360 elements. You could

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> cosineY;
std::vector<double> cosY(360); // strongly consider replacing the 360 with a well-named 
                               // constant
for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++) // same with that 8
{
   for int n=0; n < 360; n++)
   {
      cosY[n] = cos(a*vectorOfY[n]);
   }
   cosineY.push_back(cosY);
 }
```

for example, but this hangs on to `cosY` longer than you need to and could cause problems later, so I'd probably scope `cosY` by throwing the above code into a function.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> buildStageOne(std::vector<double> &vectorOfY)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> cosineY;
    std::vector<double> cosY(NumDegrees);
    for (int a = 0; a < NumVectors; a++)
    {
       for int n=0; n < NumDegrees; n++)
       {
          cosY[n] = cos(a*vectorOfY[n]); // take radians into account if needed.
       }
       cosineY.push_back(cosY);
     }
    return cosineY;
}
```

This looks horrible, returning the `vector` by value, but the vast majority of compilers will [take advantage of Copy Elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) or some other sneaky optimization to eliminate the copying.

Then I'd do almost the exact same thing for the second step.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> buildStageTwo(std::vector<double> &vectorOfY,
                                               std::vector<std::vector<double>> &cosineY)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> CosProductY;
    for (int a = 0; a < numVectors; a++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < NumDegrees; n++)
        {
           cosProductPt[n] = (VectorOfY[n]*cosineY[a][n]);
        }
        CosProductY.push_back(cosProductPt);
     }
    return CosProductY;
}
```

But we can make a couple optimizations

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> buildStageTwo(std::vector<double> &vectorOfY,
                                               std::vector<std::vector<double>> &cosineY)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> CosProductY;
    for (int a = 0; a < numVectors; a++)
    {
        // why risk constantly looking up cosineY[a]? grab it once and cache it
        std::vector<double> & cosY = cosineY[a]; // note the reference
        for (int n = 0; n < numDegrees; n++)
        {
           cosProductPt[n] = (VectorOfY[n]*cosY[n]);
        }
        CosProductY.push_back(cosProductPt);
     }
    return CosProductY;
}
```

And the next is kind of an extension of the first:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> buildStageTwo(std::vector<double> &vectorOfY,
                                               std::vector<std::vector<double>> &cosineY)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> CosProductY;
    std::vector<double> cosProductPt(360);

    for (std::vector<double> & cosY: cosineY) // range based for. Gets rid of 
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < NumDegrees; n++)
        {
           cosProductPt[n] = (VectorOfY[n]*cosY[n]);
        }
        CosProductY.push_back(cosProductPt);
     }
    return CosProductY;
}
```

We could do the same range-based for trick for the `for (int n = 0; n < NumDegrees; n++)`, but since we are iterating multiple arrays here it's not all that helpful.

Comment: Thank you for help. I did think about this but I think it is far better if I just pass my vectors of vectors by reference, rather than return them. I think I was able to solve most of my problems after posting it, without even having to wait for help. I'm not sure If I want to confuse myself more with the for loop that has a vector in brackets... I'm barely understanding my own program at this point :(. I'll take your good programming advice as I continue to develop the program, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Lukali "I think I was able to solve most of my problems after posting it, without even having to wait for help." Good! Best way to learn! Note: Good reading on the whole returning by value thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work