# Does the behavior of guaranteed copy elision depend on existence of user-defined copy constructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, copy-elision, gcc8

The following code behaves differently with or without user-defined copy constructor [under GCC 8.0.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/46p36ZShdZub7WFM):

```
#include <cassert>

struct S {
    int i;
    int *p;
    S() : i(0), p(&i) {}
    // S(const S &s) : i(s.i), p(&i) {}  // #1
    // S(const S &s) : i(s.i), p(s.p) {} // #2
    // S(const S &s) = delete;           // #3
};

S make_S() {return S{};}

int main()
{
    S s = make_S();
    assert(s.p == &s.i);
}
```

With either of the commented user-defined copy constructors (even with #2, the one performing a simple shallow copy), the assertion will not fail, which means [guaranteed copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work) works as expected.

However, without any user-defined copy constructor, the assertion fails, which means the object `s` in `main` function is not default-constructed. Why does this happen? Doesn't guaranteed copy elision perform here?

Comment: Guaranteed copy elision and RVO are not one and the same, though

Comment: Does your compiler fully support that feature?

Comment: Also worth mentioning it fails on Clang 7.0.0 as well

Comment: @StoryTeller RVO in this example meets the criteria of guaranteed copy elision. It is an initialization from a prvalue of the same class type.

Comment: @juanchopanza It seems GCC fully supports guaranteed copy elision since version 7 from [this table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: I'm probably mistaken, but I really can't find anything wrong with your example that would make the copy elision faulty. I suspect a QOI issue (for both Clang and GCC).

Comment: Just for clarification, there is no RVO in C++17, since no temporary is materialized when a prvalue is returned. There are no constructors to be elided then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting from C++17 Working Draft §15.2 Temporary Objects Paragraph 3 (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.temporary#3):

> When an object of class type X is passed to or **returned from a function**, if each copy constructor, move constructor, and destructor of X is either trivial or deleted, and X has at least one non-deleted copy or move constructor, **implementations are permitted to create a temporary object to hold** the function parameter or **result object**. ...  [ *Note*: This latitude is granted to allow objects of class type to be passed to or returned from functions in registers. — *end note*]

In your case, when I made both copy and move constructors defaulted:

```
S(const S &) = default;
S(S &&) = default;
```

assertion failed as well with GCC and Clang. Note that implicitly-defined constructors are trivial.

Comment: [And what do you know, bloating the object size for the OP's code, suddenly makes it all tick](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n7uRQNJCXVZfRPJL). I guess because it doesn't fit in a register anymore.

Comment: @StoryTeller Exactly, it just came to my mind to do the same experiment. But you were faster :)