# Copy/move elision requires explicit definition of copy/move constructors

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-constructor, move-semantics, copy-elision

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class T {
public:
    T() { printf("address at construction:    %zx\n", (uintptr_t)this); }
    // T(const T&) { printf("copy-constructed\n"); } // helps
    // T(T&&) { printf("move-constructed\n"); }      // helps
    // T(const T&) = default;                        // does not help
    // T(T&&) = default;                             // does not help
};

T f() { return T(); }

int main() {
    T x = f();
    printf("address after construction: %zx\n", (uintptr_t)&x);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp` gives the following output (same with `clang++`):

```
address at construction:    7ffcc7626857
address after construction: 7ffcc7626887
```

Based on the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) I would expect the program to output two equal addresses because the copy/move should be guaranteed to be elided (at least in C++17).

If I explicitly define either the copy or the move constructor or both (see commented out lines in the example), the program gives the expected output (even with C++11):

```
address at construction:    7ffff4be4547
address after construction: 7ffff4be4547
```

Simply setting the copy/move constructors to `default` does not help.

The reference explicitly states

> [The copy/move constructors] need not be present or accessible

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879226/does-the-behavior-of-guaranteed-copy-elision-depend-on-existence-of-user-defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because this is a special case where copy elision may not apply.

Quoted from [[class.temporary] paragraph 3](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#3):

> When an object of class type X is passed to or returned from a function, if each copy constructor, move constructor, and destructor of X is either trivial or deleted, and X has at least one non-deleted copy or move constructor, implementations are permitted to create a temporary object to hold the function parameter or result object. The temporary object is constructed from the function argument or return value, respectively, **and the function's parameter or return object is initialized as if by using the non-deleted trivial constructor to copy the temporary** (even if that constructor is inaccessible or would not be selected by overload resolution to perform a copy or move of the object). [ Note: This latitude is granted to allow objects of class type to be passed to or returned from functions in registers. — end note ]

Comment: Interesting, it seems to me though that the standard formulates this exception too broadly. The motivation for my question was that my `T` is rather large and my stack very small, so I care strongly about not duplicating the object on the stack. If this pattern occurs multiple times, adding an explicit copy constructor to every class feels like a hack though, is there anything I can do in `f()` to avoid this?

Comment: @AlGebra - But your `T` here isn't large, it is extremely small. A very small object that is constructed in a register and returned by value might not need any stack space at all. And so it might be *more efficient* than involving the RVO machinery, which at least needs some indirection.

Comment: @AlGebra: Stop second-guessing your compiler. If your *actual* `T` really is "rather large", then the compiler won't perform this optimization. So let your compiler do its job, so that you can get back to doing your job: writing a functioning program.

Comment: @BoPersson @NicolBolas Thanks for pointing this out. When adding `const int data[5] = {0};` to `T` the compiler does indeed elide the move.
However in my real use case the objects are in fact duplicated on the stack which is why I investigated this in the first place. I must have missed some other relevant detail while isolating the issue.