# Am I testing the Return Value Optimization correctly?

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

Consider:

```
struct Measures {
    char name[128]; // added in response to comments
    int   age;
    float weight;
};

Measures foo() {
    Measures res;
    cout << &res << endl;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    Measures m = foo();
    cout << &m << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get by running this code in Visual Studio is:

```
004FFA30
004FFB28
```

Do I conclude correctly from the fact that the two addresses differ that the return value optimization is not performed? If so, why would it not be performed in this case (I found several posts dealing with Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9.14) not performing the Return Value Optimization, but none of them seems to be about this particular case)?

Comment: Which version of virtual studio?

Comment: Are you testing a debug build or a release (optimized) build?

Comment: You are probably seeing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879226/does-the-behavior-of-guaranteed-copy-elision-depend-on-existence-of-user-defined - Try adding a `char b[128];` member to your structure. It surely won't fit in a register, and so you'll know if this is the case.

Comment: This is NRVO, not regular RVO.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I did. Still different addresses in the output.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I choose Release from the menu, but there is no option in Visual Studio 2017 to start without debugging. I pressed Ctrl-F5 to run the program. I get the same result by running the `.exe` file from the Release directory.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this under Visual Studio 2019, 16.4.2.
The test as posted is valid, and will show you if NRVO is happening. As other comments note, this is not the same as RVO.

Answer (score 3):

https://godbolt.org/z/FCRtY9

As hinted at in the comments, this has to do with the size of your struct. If the struct fits in registers, then the address might change.

Once you create a bigger struct, the address stays the same.

Note that copy-elision is guaranteed to occur: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48881336/461597

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Measures {
    int   age;
    float weight;
};

struct BigMeasures {
    Measures m;
    int foo, bar, moo, mar;
};

Measures foo() {
    Measures res;
    cout << &res << endl;
    return res;
}

BigMeasures bar() {
    BigMeasures res;
    std::cout << &res << "\n";
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Small Measures:\n";
    Measures m = foo();
    cout << &m << endl;
    std::cout << "Big Measures:\n";
    BigMeasures bm = bar();
    std::cout << &bm << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed the code as shown in the updated question and still see different addresses.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/o85yao This is also comparing against MSVC. The addition of your char array causes Clang to print the same address. But I cannot evaluate this on Windows.