# Confusing behaviour around mandatory elision of copy/move

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision

While toying with RVO I encountered the following issue and I can't get my head around it.

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    A* p = this;
};

A func()
{
    return A();
}

int main()
{
    A a = A();
    std::cout << "address of a: " << &a << " - a.p = " << a.p << std::endl;

    A b = func();          
    std::cout << "address of b: " << &b << " - b.p = " << b.p << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
address of a: 0x7ffe5b11b7a0 - a.p = 0x7ffe5b11b7a0

address of b: 0x7ffe5b11b790 - b.p = 0x7ffe5b11b770
```

All fine with `a`. However note that `b.p` doesn't actually point to `b` as if it was pointing to a different object.

I'm using gcc 8.3.0 which supports C++17. My understanding is that from C++17 onwards, RVO is mandatory and initialisation from a prvalue (i.e. `A b = func();`) should also trigger mandatory elision. Therefore, in theory, only one constructor should be called to initialise `b` so `p` should not be able to point to anything else than `b`.
Could someone explain me what is happening here?

Note: initialising `p` in a default constructor instead of using default member initialisation doesn't change the behaviour.

I toyed with this a bit more and realised that defining a default constructor AND any one of the following special functions makes `p` point to `b` as expected:

- destructor
- move constructor
- move assignment operator
- copy constructor

Instead of helping me understand the problem, this confused me even more...

As a side note, I have witnessed the exact same behaviour with gcc 11.0.0 and clang 11.0.0 (using [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ziw8Sns21V0bMOcp)) so this is unlikely a bug.

Comment: To get more info and data points, try adding a default constructor that dumps `this` to `std::cout`, and see what that gives you.

Comment: Indeed, I've done that as a test and it was always equal to p.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#3.sentence-1

Comment: Interestingly, if the copy constructor is defined as deleted, then it behaves as expected. Edit: Rule linked by cpplearner explains this.

Comment: @eeroika Here is [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2OMCdIgmIfnWldJJ). When the deleted definitions are removed, addresses are different. It's totally weird.

Comment: Small trivial object, same answer here applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879226/does-the-behavior-of-guaranteed-copy-elision-depend-on-existence-of-user-defined (probably a duplicate).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Nice finding, don't remember my own answers ;-). Just a note that the rule was likely motivated by passing objects in registers, while here we explicitly require them to be in memory to be addressed.

Comment: Thanks to cpplearner and StoryTeller. It looks like a duplicate indeed. So if I understand this properly, this is a case where a temporary can be created by the compiler and p points to that temporary.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica A tangential topic: do you believe cppreference's [page on copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is inaccurate w.r.t. this temporary object corner case? Particularly the section _Mandatory elision of copy/move operations_, which seems to cover return value elision solely from the perspective of _"unmaterialized value passing"_ whereas, as your linked answer covers, a temporary _may_ actually be materialized in some circumstances.

Comment: @dfri - Not so much inaccurate as incomplete. It's correct in asserting that no value is materialized (as opposed to elided). But it doesn't cover when materialization should/may occur.