# Best way to use emplace_back to avoid move constructor call?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, emplace

I just learned about [guaranteed copy elision in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work). According to the answer on that question:

> When you do `return T();`, this initializes the return value of the
>   function via a `prvalue`. Since that function returns T, no temporary is
>   created; the initialization of the `prvalue` simply directly initializes
>   the return value.
>
> The thing to understand is that, since the return value is a `prvalue`,
>   it is not an object yet. It is merely an initializer for an object,
>   just like `T()` is.

So I was wondering, does this work for anything other than:

```
T f() {return T();}
T t = f();
```

So I wrote this code with `emplace_back` to test it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct BigObj{
  BigObj() = default;
  BigObj(int) { std::cout << "int ctor called" << std::endl;  }
  BigObj(const BigObj&){
    std::cout << "copy ctor called" << std::endl;
  }
  BigObj(BigObj&&){
    std::cout << "move ctor called" << std::endl;
  }
};
BigObj f(){ return BigObj(2); }
int g(){ return 2; }
int main(){
  std::vector<BigObj> v;
  v.reserve(10);
  std::cout << "emplace_back with rvalue \n";
  v.emplace_back(1+1);
  std::cout << "emplace_back with f()\n";
  v.emplace_back(f());
  std::cout << "emplace_back with g()\n";
  v.emplace_back(g());
}
```

This is the output I get (with copy elision disabled):

```
emplace_back with rvalue 
int ctor called
emplace_back with f()
int ctor called
move ctor called
emplace_back with g()
int ctor called
```

It seems that the move constructor is still called even though a `prvalue` is passed directly into `emplace_back`, which I thought could be used to directly construct an object instead of being used to construct a temporary and then moving it.

Is there a more elegant way to avoid the move constructor call with `emplace_back` other than doing something like what the `g()` function does?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> It seems that the move constructor is still called even though a prvalue is passed directly into emplace_back

You think you do, but you don't pass it *into* the function. You give it a prvalue as argument, yes, but what `emplace_back` accepts is a pack of *forwarding **references***. A reference must refer to an object, so a [temporary is materialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.rval#1), and moved.

The correct way to use `emplace_back` is to pass it the arguments for initializing the object *in place*. That way you don't need to move the element type of the vector (though you may need to move/copy the arguments).

Comment: So when a prvalue is passed into any function that accepts any kind of reference (const reference or rvalue reference), by necessity a temporary is constructed?

Comment: @user2108462 - Yes. Binding to references is a place where temporary materialization would occur. It must happen so we get the object being referred to.

Comment: @StoryTeller, ah, reading comprehension fail on my part—the comment itself actually says prvalue.

Comment: Of course, what would be cool is to call `v.emplace_back(f);` i.e. don't immediately execute f(), but pass the factory function into emplace to execute at an appropriate time. To do it generically with std::function would be overkill for a simple object, though.

Comment: @GemTaylor - Can't you do something like that with expression templates or an equivalent technique? Maybe? Would be nice to have it available without boiler-plate, however, indeed.

Comment: Indeed. I imagine it would look something like the horror that is c++11 std:::map emplace pair, or perhaps std::thread.