# Initialise const std::vector Class Members Efficiently

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, constructor

Lets assume I am trying to create "immutable" class objects (i.e. members variables are defined with `const`). So when calling the constructor I currently call separate `init` functions to initialise the class members. But as a result there seems to be a lot of new vector-creating & vector-copying going on.

If the members weren't `const` I could perform the initialisations in the `{ }` section of the constructor and write directly into `values` (which I assume would be more efficient). But this is not possible.

Are there better/cleaner/more efficient ways to design the construction of immutable classes?

```
#include <vector>

class Data
{
public:
    const std::vector<int> values;

    Data(unsigned int size, int other) : values(init(size, other)) { }
    Data(const std::vector<int>& other) : values(init(other)) { }

private:
    std::vector<int> init(unsigned int size, int other) {
        std::vector<int> myVector(size);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            myVector[i] = other * i;

        return myVector;
    }

    std::vector<int> init(const std::vector<int>& other) {
        std::vector<int> myVector(other);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i)
            myVector[i] *= myVector[i] - 1;

        return myVector;
    }
};

int main() {
    Data myData1(5, 3);         // gives {0, 3, 6, 9, 12}
    Data myData2({2, 5, 9});    // gives {2, 20, 72}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a lot of copying? Have you benchmarked anything?

Comment: I would expect the local vector from `init()` to be moved into the member, there should be no copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current design is perfectly fine. The initialization takes place in the constructor's member initialization list, so it will trigger a move at worst (which is quite cheap for a vector anyway) and **NRVO** at best.

**NRVO** is ***Named Return Value Optimization***. When a function returns a named variable with automatic storage duration, the compiler is allowed to elide the copy/move. Note that however, copy/move constructors still need to be available even in the case of an elision. Here is a dummy example to sum up that concept:

```
SomeType foo() { // Return by value, no ref
    SomeType some_var = ...; // some_var is a named variable
                             // with automatic storage duration
    do_stuff_with(var);
    return some_var; // NRVO can happen
}
```

(Your `init` function follows that pattern.)

In C++17 you could even benefit from a guaranteed copy elision in that scenario depending on the shape of your init function. You can find out more about this in this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043447/1794345).

*Note: Since you tagged your question [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) I assume move semantics are available.*

Answer (score 1):

You say

> there seems to be a lot of new vector-creating & vector-copying going on.

But I am unsure of it. I would instead expect one full creation and one move here:
`init` builds and returns a temporary vector (ok full vector creation, directly with the final size) which is used to initialize the const member (ok a move should occur here). We should control the generated assembly here, but a decent compiler should build the data block once, and move it into the data member.

So unless you can prove by profiling (or by looking at the assembly generated by your compiler) that things really need to be optimized here, I would gladly keep on with this code because it clearly declares the member constness.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to remove `const` from the member vector so that you can perform your initialisation in place, rather than by copying.

If you want `values` to be readable but not writable by users of the class, you can expose a `const` reference to it:

```
class Data {
    std::vector<int> values_;

    // constructors...

public:
    std::vector<int> const& values() const { return values_; }
};
```

Comment: For me it is bad design to expose a reference to internal data. If the instance of the class is owner of the data, it makes sense to place the operations also in that class. Exceptionally the class is designed only as container, but this use case must be well founded.