# Copy initialization and explicit

Tags: c++, initialization

First try:

```
class Local {
 public:
    Local() {std::cout << "default\n"; }
    Local(const Local&) {std::cout << "copy ctor!\n"; }
};

int main() {
    // Direct list init -> Value init -> Default init
    Local obj{};

    // Copy initialization -> non-explicit copy ctor
    Local obj_one = obj;

    // Temporary value init -> Copy initialization -> non-explicit copy ctor 
    Local obj_two = Local{};

    return 0;
}
```

Second try (add `explicit`):

```
class Local {
 public:
    Local() {std::cout << "default\n"; }
    // now here explicit
    explicit Local(const Local&) {std::cout << "copy ctor!\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Local obj{};

    // (1) Error, copy-initialization does not consider explicit constructor
    Local obj_one = obj;

    // (2) Why there is no error?
    Local obj_two = Local{};

    return 0;
}
```

In case (1) everything - fine.
But what about case (2)?
I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initialization) that in case (2):

> Value-initializes a temporary and then copies that value into c2 (Read
>   5.2.3/2 and 8.6/14). This of course will **require a non-explicit copy constructor** (Read 8.6/14 and 12.3.1/3 and 13.3.1.3/1 ).

```
clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp
```

Comment: What's the question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @nicomp I don't understand why copy init works with explicit ctor

Comment: You should put that prominently in your question.

Comment: It works because of [mandatory copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/241631). If you change `-std=c++17` to an earlier standard version, the second line will fail to compile too.

Comment: @Praetorian The answer section is below ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver heh, I was tempted to, but Nicol's got an excellent answer on that already