# Is it possible to initialize variable with lambda (when copy ctor is deleted)?

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization, c++17

I have the following the code:

```
struct A {//<-- Third party library class
  A(){};
  A(const A&) = delete;
  void init(){};
  int i;
};


int f(){
  static A a = []{
    A res; 
    res.init(); 
    return res;
    }();
  return a.i;
}
```

see it live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5c5912bd79053c3

And it gives the following error when compiled:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

main.cpp: In lambda function:

main.cpp:12:12: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'

     return res;

            ^~~

main.cpp:4:3: note: declared here

   A(const A&) = delete;

   ^
```

**I know I could wrap this in a another `struct` and initialize in that constructor**, but it just seems somewhat tedious.
Using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), do we have a 'neat' way around this 'problem' ?

**Any solution must work equally well for a static var in a function**

Comment: What's wrong with `A a {}; a.init();` or calling `init` in A's constructor?

Comment: Can't you support `move constructor`?

Comment: A is in my case a CFont (MS third party) - so cannot modify

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you cant call `a.init()`on file scope like that - or for a static variable in a function

Comment: If you could allocate on the heap instead of the stack, you could use your IIFE to return a `unique_ptr<A>`. If you really need ref semantics, you could then declare a reference: `A& a2 = *a;` (Also, beware the [static init order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).)

Comment: So if the sole motivation for all this is just that it's needed to facilitate the use of this `init()` method, then why not just get rid of `init()`!? It's generally a very bad practice to have `init()` methods because it's error prone and it implies that there are objects in your program that, at points, exist in a zombie state…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel That would be best indeed ! however the issue here is that class is 3rd party (`CFont` in actual case). And then you cannot do for example `static const myfont = "something" `. The only way is as the answer suggests or wrap in another class (but that is just less expressive i think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your class is not moveable, and the copy constructor is deleted/not accessible, then you don't have any choice but to return a reference to a static object, or to return a pointer.  This is because C++17's [guaranteed copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work) only works with prvalues.  Since the object has a name in the lambda, it has to be able to be moved or copied it into the return object, even if NRVO is applied.

You can use

```
A& a = []() -> A& {
    static A res; 
    res.init(); 
    return res;
}();
```

or

```
auto a = []{
    auto res = std::make_unique<A>(); 
    res->init(); 
    return res;
}();
```

Comment: This is somewhat what i gathered as well. Keeping the question open for a bit.

Comment: @NathanOliver which of the two possible approaches would you personally prefer?

Comment: @darune No worries.  It's unfortunate that MS didn't make the type moveable.  Maybe they will update it one day.

Comment: @StackDanny Tough choice.  I'm leaning towards the `unique_ptr` as it naturally translates into a factory function approach for building multiple `A`'s.  The static approach doesn't work for that since they would all be sharing a single instance.  This is doubly so if multi-threading is in play.

Answer (score -1):

You can call `init` on default constructor. Then, you can have this on static functions and static member functions. It is also possible to use copy elision on prvalues and provide something like `A res = []{ return A(); }();`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {//Third party library class
  constexpr A() :i{}
  { init(); };
  A(const A&) = delete;
  constexpr void init(){ i = 5; };
  int i;
};

struct A_User {
    static constexpr void A_print() {
        constexpr A res{};
        static_assert(res.i == 5);
    }
};

A& static_func() {
    static A res{};
    std::cout << "res static: " << res.i << "\n";
    return res;
}

A res = []{ return A(); /* copy elided since this is prvalue */ }();

int main() {
    std::cout << "res global: " << res.i << "\n";
    auto& static_A = static_func();
}
```

Comment: this is too far away from problem or only half of an answer - it will only work for global (and my actual case is a static var in function) and the other issue is that it could be needed before entering main function

Comment: We can do `A res = []{ return A(); }();` for globals but as others pointed, seems like there is no way to return a `static A` by value from a function.