# Why does the string introduced by the sv suffix not expire?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, string-view

It is a common mistake to initialize a `std::string_view` with a temporary `std::string`.

```
using namespace std::literals;

std::string_view sv1 = "foo" ; // good
std::string_view sv2 = "bar"s; // bad: "foo"s will expire

std::cout << sv1 << "\n"       // outputs foo
          << sv2 << "\n";      // undefined behavior
```

That's because `"bar"s`, the temporary `std::string`, is destroyed at the end of the *full-expression*.

But how about `"foo"sv`?

```
std::string_view sv3 = "baz"sv;
```

Of course this should work, because the suffix `sv` is otherwise useless. But how is this fundamentally different from `"baz"s`? In other words, why does the string introduced by `"baz"sv` not expire?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Why the declaration of `sv2` is bad

Per [[basic.string.literals]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.string.literals#1):

> ```
> string operator""s(const char* str, size_t len);
> ```
>
> *Returns:* `string{str, len}`.

In `"foo"s`, the string literal `"foo"` is used to initialize a temporary `std::string`. The characters are copied to the underlying array of the temporary `std::string`. `std::string_view` is a non-owning view, and `sv2` points to the underlying array of the temporary `std::string`. After the temporary `std::string` is destroyed, `sv2` keeps pointing to the (now expired) underlying array, and trying to output `sv2` results in undefined behavior.

## Why the declaration of `sv3` is good

Per [[string.view.literals]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.view.literals#1):

> ```
> constexpr string_view operator""sv(const char* str, size_t len) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Returns:* `string_­view{str, len}`.

Therefore, the declaration of `sv3` is equivalent to:<sup>1</sup>

```
std::string_view sv3{"baz", 3};
```

`sv3` directly points to the string literal `"baz"`. A string literal has static storage duration and does not expire.

<sup>1</sup> There is some subtlety here. Copy elision [may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work) or [may not](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.temporary#3) apply here. Since `string_view`s are non-owning, copying `string_view`s does not introduce new temporary strings. Therefore, regardless of whether a copy is to take place, the state of `sv3` is the same.

Comment: Even without copy elision `sv3` is safe, since there is no heap, nor stack, in sight. 
With no elision, a non-owning temporary is created with data from the executable itself, let's call it "global data". When it's pointer/size are copied to the `sv3` over the function boundary, the temporary is destroyed, but, since it was non-owning, no memory is released, as it always was part of a segment in the binary.

So now `sv3` is a safe view into that memory.

Comment: @MarcinZdun Yes. Copy elision is not the most important point here. The point is that the string view is initialized directly from the string literal instead of a temporary `std::string`. That said, it feels strange to disregard the fact that C++17 guarantees copy elision :)

Comment: @L.F. I agree copy elision is nice, but you put so much emphasis on it that it is sounds like copy ellision is necessary to get "`sv3` directly points to the string literal `"baz"`" statement true. Currently you read: "Why the declaration of sv3 is good -> Therefore, by guaranteed copy elision (...)". So the follow up question would be "how about `string_view` copies?" We both know they point directly to static `"baz"` as well. I'd state "A string literal has static storage duration and does not expire." to anwer header question in the first place, then leave remark about copy elision.

Comment: @R2RT Well, I partially agree with your comment. First, I was just analyzing the underlying process, and copy elision was one of the steps. We shouldn't discriminate on it just because it sounds fancy ;-) But you are right in that I am putting too much emphasis on it, and my wording suggests that the omission of copying is essential for `sv3` to work. I have updated my answer to remove this potential inaccuracy.

Comment: Let me add: [implementations are allowed not to elide copies here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.temporary#3) (and do not if the function is not inlined)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer OK ... Now I see that I am completely wrong. Thank you for informing me of this! I have updated my answer to reflect that.