# C++ proper way to inline initialize member variables

Tags: c++, class, struct, initialization, member-variables

Given the example code:

```
struct S {
    char data[5];
    int a;
};
```

When running the "Run code analysis" in Microsoft Visual Studio, It warns to initialize all variables.

Now I know you can do this a number of ways, create a default constructor such as:

```
S() :
    data{0},
    a{0} {
}
```

That makes the warning go away. But what if you don't want to manually create the default constructor.

something like:

```
struct S {
    char data[5];
    int a = 0;
};
```

gets rid of the warning for `a` but not `data`, though you can fix that by adding `{}` after like so: `char data[5]{};` this seems to make the code analysis happy.

That got me thinking, you can also initialize `a` like `int a{0};`

So my question is, are these all valid, and which is preferred?

Side note: I noticed `std::array` has `_Ty _Elems[_Size];` which it never initializes anywhere, nor does it have `{}` after it, I'm assuming they just ignore this warning? Or are they doing something I'm not noticing to "fix" the warning?

Also wanted to add that this code:
    #include 
    #include

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct static_vector {
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N] = {0};

    T& operator[](std::size_t pos)  {
        return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[pos]));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char**) {
    static_vector<int, 10> s;
    s[0] = argc;
    return s[0];
}
```

under `gcc9.1 -std=c++17 -Wall` produces no warnings,
yet the same code under `clang8.0 -std=c++17 -Wall` gives me:

```
warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]
        typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N] = {0};
                                                                              ^
                                                                              {}
```

I see that I can set it to `= {};` which fixes it, just wondering why one compiler would produce a warning when the other doesn't? Which one is to spec?

Comment: `{}` is a fairly good way to do it, works everywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guideline from [CPPCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#main) on this states: [Don’t define a default constructor that only initializes data members; use in-class member initializers instead](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#c45-dont-define-a-default-constructor-that-only-initializes-data-members-use-in-class-member-initializers-instead)

So you can just do:

```
struct S {
    char data[5] = {0};
    int a = 0;
};
```

As to your other question about the lack of warning related to `std::array`, GCC has a note which states:

> Warnings from system headers are normally suppressed, on the assumption that they usually do not indicate real problems and would only make the compiler output harder to read.

I believe this would be true of MSVC as well.

Comment: So for c-arrays/std::arrays/std::vectors, etc, I should use `= {0};` as the "proper" way to initialize those data members? The reason I ask is because as I understand it, using = over just {} causes potential overhead? for instance, `std::string a("Hello World");` is preferred over `std::string = "Hello World"` as the 2nd one creates two instances of string, etc?

Comment: @HexCrown: In case of primitive types, there is no difference. But if they are user-defined types, there are certain differences. BTW, the two kinds of initializations are called direct initialization and copy initialization. The differences are explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initialization).

Comment: I am a bit confused by the given reasoning (not included in your answer). How can the compiler generate a defaullt constructor that is more efficient than a self-written one that does nothing but initialize members?

Comment: I opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272431/how-can-a-compiler-generated-default-constructor-be-more-efficient-than-a-self-w) on that

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: You must be referring to the text in the link. The text only says "The compiler-generated function ***can*** be more efficient". I think it is because the compiler is free to make certain optimizations for the constructor it generates that it may not be able to for a user-defined constructor.

Comment: @P.W yes I noticed that it says "can", but I fail to see what the compiler generated constructor could do better in the given example (or in any other example)

Comment: @HexCrown Prior to C++17, `std::string a = "Hello world"` is allowed as an optimization to create only one instance of string, and implementations do that quite well. Since C++17, this is [guaranteed copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work).

Comment: @P.W I was messing around in https://godbolt.org/ and under clang, doing `int data[5];` produces significantly less assembly than any form of that where data is initialized, ie `int data[5]{};`, `int data[5] = {0};`, etc. Yet under gcc the opposite is true, adding the initialization part seems to create less assembly than initializing it. Any idea whats going on there?

Comment: @HexCrown: Compilers may have different approaches to optimization of code. You can ask a question about this issue if needed. There are some on SO who are very familiar with the inner workings of Clang and GCC and they might answer your question.

Comment: @HexCrown did you do that in debug mode on VS? debugging  code there does a lot of extra things, e.g. external hooks to facilitate remote debugging of memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ for each declarator, the initializer may be one of the following:

```
1. ( expression-list )
2. = expression 
3. { initializer-list }
```

The description for these are as follows:

1. comma-separated list of arbitrary expressions and braced-init-lists in parentheses
2. the equals sign followed by an expression
3. braced-init-list: possibly empty, comma-separated list of expressions and other braced-init-lists

Well which type of initialization to prefer actually depends upon context. To initialize data members in a class I personally **prefer** in class initialization using `braced initializer`, as in that case we don't have to write a user defined `default constructor`, *compiler generated one is always efficient*.

> **Class members**
>
> Non-static data members can be initialized with [member initializer
>   list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) or with a [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

In your case you can probably use:

```cpp
struct S {
    char data[5] = {0}; //initialize by zero
    int a = 0;
};
```

or to give them different values also:

```
struct S {
    char data[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int a = 0;
};
```

For more info see [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)