# Overloading operator using reference and not

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have question, in this case should I use reference to overload operator or shouldn't?

Everything works fine with and without reference.

```
Vector & operator +=( const Vector & v )
{
    this->x += v.x;
    this->y += v.y;
    return * this;
}
```

```
Vector operator +=( const Vector v )
{
    this->x += v.x;
    this->y += v.y;
    return * this;
}
```

So which option is better to use?

Comment: You changed the return type too—is that part of your question or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention, when overloading `operator +=`, is to return a non-`const` reference. This stems from how the `+=` operator natively works with primitive types in C++. Although it's very, very unusual to see code like the following in C++, it's perfectly legal:

```
int x = 137;
(x += 42) += 161;
```

The above code is only meaningful if the expression `(x += 42)` evaluates to `x` itself as an lvalue. Consequently, you should return a reference to the underlying object.

Answer (score 4):

Use the reference one. Otherwise you are creating an unnecessary copy. 
Learn more: [pass by value or by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

[Guaranteed copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work) since C++17 might occur, but nevertheless, stick to good practices.

Comment: Copy elision might apply?

Comment: How can copy elision apply? Since `*this` is not running out of scope? `int x; int y = x+=1;` has to create a copy somewhere.

Comment: Worse than that. If you string a bunch of assignments together like `a += b += c`, not returning a reference will not modify the original object as you would expect, since you are only working with a copy.