# Copy constructor call for temporary object

Tags: c++

I have a following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    A() {}
    A(const A&)  { cout << "copy const" << endl; }
    A(A&)  { cout << "copy non const" << endl; }
};
A f(A a)
{
    return a;
}
int main() {
  A a1 = f(A());
}
```

The `A(A&)` copy constructor is called. Why `A(const A&)` is not called since I pass a temporary object?
When I comment out the `A(const A&)` copy constructor the program does not compile.

Comment: Live example with gcc 9.2 : https://godbolt.org/z/585J59

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are seeing is a mix of [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) and an actual copy being made.  Since `f` takes `a` by value, It needs to copy `A()` into `a`. The compiler sees this copy really isn't needed, so it elides that and instead directly constructs `a` so you don't see any call.  In the body of `f` when you `return a;`, it needs to copy `a` into the return value.  Since `a` is a lvalue, `A(A&)` is a better match than `A(const A&)` so you see the call to the non const copy constructor.  Then `a1` needs to be initialized from `f`'s return value.  Again copy elision comes into play again and instead of seeing a copy it just directly puts the return value into `a1`'s storage.

So, elide, non-const copy, elide, which leaves the output with just `copy non const`

---

You get an error when you remove `A(const A&)` because even though those copies were elided, C++ still required there to be copy constructor until C++17.

---

If you compile with gcc or clang and use `-fno-elide-constructors` you can actually see those copies.  You can see that in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a85a7b4f88f4594).  Note that I used `-std=c++11` to turn off C++17's [guaranteed copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work)

Comment: I never gave a thought to the return value. Great catch.

Comment: I thought mandatory copy-elision would not come into play here since we are returning a named object? But I can see it does compile in `c++17` and later with the `const A&` version commented out. What am I missing?

Comment: Right, that's the only place there is no elided copy. I'm confusing myself... :-) Thanks.

Comment: @super Actually, [its working here with no copies](https://godbolt.org/z/S2hmtb).  IIRC though, since it is a function parameter that is by value, its allowed to be elided.

Comment: Nope, [I recalled incorrectly](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.elision#1.1).  It's that when I commented them all out, the compiler implicitly made one, and then elided that.

Comment: Great answer! `non const copy constructor` - technically, there is no such thing. This is a converting constructor, which looks similar to the copy constructor.

Comment: @Mikhail Actually there is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.ctor#3.  `T(T&)` and `T(const T&)` are both copy constructors.

Comment: This brings up the question: why is RVO not mandatory for xvalues or lvalues?

Comment: @Timo RVO is guaranteed to function local lvalues.  `A foo() { A named; return named; }` will RVO, even though `named` is an lvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver is this actually guaranteed? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) doesn't mention it, but I guess they're not the standard.

Comment: And if it was guaranteed, wouldn't OPs example yield no ctor call at all, since the function argument is also a local lvalue?

Comment: @Timo Nope, cppreference is right.  I missed the it the standard says *can be omitted*

Comment: @NathanOliver Wow, thanks for the link! That's not what cppreference says.

Comment: @Mikhail technically it's tagged as a note, so if it's not explicitly written elsewhere it's debatable if it's one or the other.

Comment: Here is a source of the same thing for normative text that `T(T&)` is a copy constructor: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.ctor#7

Comment: :) ok I surrender.

Comment: @Mikhail Can you point me to the page you're talking about?  I'll see if I can't edit it to make it correct.

Comment: This answer only applies to pre-C++17.  Since C++17 there is no copy to elide,  instead when an object is initialized by prvalue of the same type, the prvalue's result object is the object being initialized .

Comment: @NathanOliver I was looking at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor But now I see that I failed to read the very first paragraph and was looking only on syntax declarations =D Where `const` is specified unconditionally.