# Initialize a constant vector of pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, embedded

I have the following classes in a header file designed to create runtime polymorphism for a set of instructions that describe system states in an embedded environment:

```
class foo
{
public:
  virtual void bar(void) = 0;
  virtual ~foo() {}
};

class derived1 : public foo
{
private:
  int data1;
public:
  void bar(void)
  {
    //implementation 1
  };
  derived1(int d) : data1(d) {}
  ~derived1() {}
};

class derived2 : public foo
{
private:
  int data2;
public:
  void bar(void)
  {
    //implementation 2
  }
  derived2(int d) : data2(d) {}
  ~derived2() {}
};
```

What is the best way to initialize a vector of type `const vector<foo*>`? I am currently doing the following:

```
const std::vector<foo*> v =
{   
  new derived1(a),
  new derived1(b),
  new derived2(c),
  new derived2(d)
};
```

Given the `const` qualifier, is this memory still dynamically allocated? It is stored in an anonymous namespace for use by several state classes. Because many state classes share the same elements I wanted to define the vector for all of them to chose from to save code space. Is a vector best suited for this behavior?

Ps, I do not need to worry about calling `delete` on any of the pointers since the application requires this information for all runtime.

Comment: `const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> v = { new derived1(a), new derived1(b), ...... }` seems like a good option

Comment: Not quite sure what exactly you are aiming for. Do you NOT want these dynamically allocated? In case this matters to you, as used `const` means the pointers cannot be changed, but nothing is going to protect the pointed-at objects from being changed.

Comment: For embedded systems design, you should simply ban the following items: dynamic allocation, `std::vector`, STL, C++11, C++.

Comment: For this implementation, static allocation may be better since the data needs to be accessible during the entire runtime, though using a vector gives me more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given the `const` qualifier, is this memory still dynamically allocated?

Yes. `std::vector` internally allocates and `const` or no `const` won't change that.

> What is the best way to initialize a vector of type `const vector<foo*>`?

*Best* is really subjective here, but there are generally two good ways I like to use:

- initialise with braces to use `std::initializer_list`;
- use [IIFE](https://www.bfilipek.com/2016/11/iife-for-complex-initialization.html) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression);

The first one is obvious - you are already using it. The second one is tricker if you've never used that:

```
const std::vector<int> vec = [someFlag]{
    std::vector<int> non_const;

    non_const.push_back(3);
    if (someFlag) {
        non_const.push_back(-1);
    }
    non_const.push_back(7);

    return non_const;
}(); // <= notice the call - ()
```

Notice that you end up with a `const std::vector` which is *conditionally initialised* (notice the `if` inside the lambda). The trick is to use a lambda and a local, non-`const` vector to push some values into it and then `return` it. <s>Due to mandatory copy elision, there should be exactly one contruction of `std::vector`</s>. The compiler is free to optimise (and likely will) any vector copies, so most of the time there will be just one `std::vector` creation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work  (see end of top answer)

Comment: Thanks for the IIFE initializer! I haven't seen this one before, but I like it because of the added functionality. Probably not necessary for the above implementation, but may be useful elsewhere.