# Is C++17 copy elision applied to placement new?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am writing a generic interface for scripting languages and need to call functions that return an object and put the resulting object in a space provided by the scripting language.
I have tested with clang++ on Mac OS and the following seems to do the copy/move elision:

```
class T {
public:
    T() {}
    T(const T &t) {
        std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl;
    }
    T(T&&t) : x(t.x) {
        std::cout << "Move" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int x = 3;
};

T h()
{
    return T();
}

void buildTInto(void *p)
{
    new (p) T(h());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    alignas(T) char space[sizeof(T)];
    buildTInto(space);
}
```

Running this code does not print anything.
Reading [the cpp reference description of copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) seems to indicate this is the correct behavior, given the example they give which only calls one constructor:

```
T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
```

I think my code is very much similar as without copy elision, the move constructor would be called (just like the `T(T(f()))` would call two move construction).

Not being a spec lawyer, I am curious if my understanding is correct and I wonder if all C++17 capable compilers do this correctly?

Comment: FYI: don't discard the return value of the `new` expression; you should use it instead of casting `space` to a `T*`.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are right but I didn't understand what you meant or how to do it until I read your answer I accepted. I was going to ask you for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guaranteed elision (aka: C[++17's definition of prvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043447/734069)) applies to the initialization of *any* object of type `T` with a prvalue of the same type. That includes objects created by `new` expressions, including placement `new` forms.

Indeed, you don't even have to repeat the type at the point of invoking the `new` expression: `new(p) auto(h());` ensures the obligate condition for guaranteed elision.

Comment: This is the first time I see this syntax of auto for a constructor. Have you tested if other compilers do this correctly? I read some older Visual Studio versions did not use to do copy elision correctly.

Comment: @Michel: The syntax has been legal since `auto` deduction was introduced in C++11. Whether the given object would be moved from or constructed in place was, pre-C++17, a matter for the compiler to decide. And since you used the "C++17" tag in your question, talking about the behavior of pre-C++17-compliant compilers is kind of irrelevant.