# Tour of C++ copy elision in Section 4.2.3

Tags: c++, c++17, move, move-semantics, copy-elision

I'm reading Section 4.2.3 Initializing Containers, *Tour of C++ Second Edition*.

It says:

> ```cpp
> Vector read(istream& is)
> {
>      Vector v;
>      for (double d; is>>d;)
>          v.push_back(d);
>      return v;
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>   The way to provide `Vector` with a move constructor, so that returning a potentially huge amount of data from `read()` is cheap, is explained in §5.2.2:
>
> ```cpp
> Vector v = read(cin);  // no copy of Vector elements here
> ```

Is it guaranteed that the above expression will be copy-elided (in C++17)?
I think `v` in the return is an lvalue & a local variable, so it *can* be copy-elided but is not guaranteed to be elided.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: In Pre-C++17 it was not guaranteed, in C++17 onwards it is guaranteed. I do believe someone will answer this question with tons of references.

Comment: @Croolman Is it true? As far as I know, only prvalues in return statements are guaranteed to be copy-elided in C++17 onwards. I'm not an expert, so please let me know if it is not the case.

Comment: NRVO is not guaranteed in C++17, so the move constructor still needs to be visible.

Comment: Or rather, this: [How does guaranteed copy elision work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/9716597)

Comment: @L.F. Thank you for the comments. I'm actually aware of the first question, and I just checked the second one. It says that NRVO is not guaranteed, as you mentioned. I was trying to make sure if I was correct, as the book is written by Stroustup himself. So apparantly, he oversimplified the problem, am I right?

Comment: @JayLee Stroustrup wrote "no copy of elements" which is accurate.  If NRVO doesn't apply here, the move constructor is (guaranteed to be) called instead of copy constructor, per [\[class.copy.elision\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3.1).  So elements are guaranteed to be left untouched, regardless of whether NRVO is applied.

Comment: @L.F. Oh.. I have been blinded by concentrating on the `v` itself. Thank you for clarifying, it solved my question! (I'm not sure if the other SO posts you linked answers my question tho.)

Comment: @ChrisMM The last sentence of the accepted answer is the point I needed a clarification.

Comment: @JayLee Hopefully, this problem will be gone in C++23: wg21.link/p2025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that the above expression will be copy-elided (in C++17)?
>
> I think v in the return is an lvalue & a local variable, so it can be copy-elided but is not guaranteed to be elided. Am I missing something here?

From [copy_elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

> Non-mandatory elision of copy/move (since C++11) operations
>
> In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a function parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value optimization".

So NRVO is not guarantied, even in C++17.

But, if not applied, move-constructor is done (See [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes) for details).