# C++ why does this construction even works?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering why this code compiles correctly. Since the copy-constructor and assignement-operator are deleted, I thought these mechanics would not be available.

I'm thinking that the constructions in `main()` are substituted by the compiler with some kind of `emplace` construction effectively made by `Object` itself... but I couldn't figure why or how that would happen.

```cpp
struct Object
{
private:
    friend struct ObjectFactory;
    Object() {}
    Object(const Object& other) = delete;
    Object& operator=(const Object&) const = delete;
};

struct ObjectFactory
{
    static Object CreateObject() { return Object(); }
};

int main()
{
    Object object1 = ObjectFactory::CreateObject();
    Object object2 ( ObjectFactory::CreateObject() );
    Object object3 { ObjectFactory::CreateObject() };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering why this code compiles correctly. Since the copy-constructor and assignment-operator are deleted, I thought these mechanics would not be available.

Your code wouldn't compile with C++11 or C++14. However, since C++17 – thanks to [*guaranteed copy elision*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work)  – a function can return a *prvalue* even if the type isn't *copyable* or *movable*.

---

Note that this only applies when returning prvalues. For example, if you define your `CreateObject()` so that the expression in the `return` statement isn't a prvalue but an *lvalue*:

```
static Object CreateObject() {
   Object object;
   return object; // <-- lvalue, not a prvalue
}
```

This function will not even compile with C++17:

> `error: call to deleted constructor of 'Object'`