# Why this code is not calling move constructor?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I have this simple piece of code in C++17 and I was expecting that the move constructor was called (or the copy constructor, if I was doing something wrong), while it is just calling the *normal* constructor and I cannot why is doing this *optimization*.

I am compiling with `-O0` option.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
  int m_x;

  Foo(int x) : m_x(x) { cout << "Ctor" << endl; }

  Foo(const Foo &other) : m_x(other.m_x) { cout << "Copy ctor" << endl; }

  Foo(Foo &&other) : m_x(other.m_x) {
    other.m_x = 0;
    cout << "Move ctor" << endl;
  }
};

void drop(Foo &&foo) {}

int main() { drop(Foo(5)); }
```

Comment: You're passing an `int` and not an `Foo` object.

Comment: It's not "optimisation". It's C++17 (the standard) mandated behaviour. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/817643

Comment: In C++, a *constructor* has a specific semantic, and it **can be** (pre-C++17) elided or **must be** (C++17 and later) elided under some circumstances.  Any side-effects (such as in the OP code) are not guaranteed to be executed, and should only be benign (as they are in the OP code, since they are just used for logging), and not relied upon or critical.

Comment: Single parameter constructors should _always_ be marked `explicit` - https://www.sjbrown.co.uk/posts/always-use-explicit/

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot why is doing this optimization.

This is not due to any optimization in C++17. Instead this is due to the fact that you're passing an `int` when you wrote  `Foo(5)`. And since you've provided a **converting constructor** `Foo::Foo(int)`, it will be used to create a `Foo` object which will then be bound to the *rvalue reference* parameter of `drop`.

Note that in C++17, even if we were to make the parameter of `drop` to be of type `Foo` instead of `Foo&&`, then also there will be no call to the move constructor because of [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations).

---

##### C++11

On the other hand, if you were using C++11 and using the flag `-fno-elide-constructors` and parameter to `drop` was of type `Foo` instead of `Foo&&` then you could see that a call would be made to the move ctor.

```
//--------vvv-----------> parameter is of type Foo instead of Foo&&
void drop(Foo foo) {
    
    std::cout<<"drop called"<<std::endl;
    
    }

int main() { 
    drop(Foo(5)); //in c++11 with -fno-elide-constructors the move ctor will be called
}
```

The output of the above modified version in C++11 with `-fno-elide-constructors` is:

```
Ctor
Move ctor
drop called
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gE3Sr4lVO0YW1Jr7)

Answer (score 1):

In function `main` you create a temporary `Foo` object from integer `5` but you don't move (nor copy) from it anywhere. To actually call your move (or copy) constructor, you have to move- (or copy-) construct another object from your temporary `Foo`.

E.g., to call `Foo`'s move constructor:

```
void drop(Foo &&foo) {
    // Move-construct tmp from foo.
    Foo tmp { std::move(foo) };
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that since I am passing a temporary object (so a rvalue) it should call the move constructor (since `drop` is taking a rvalue reference as input parameter). That it is what is confusing me.

Comment: @KillKRT The move constructor will be called in C++11 when the parameter of `drop` function is of type `Foo` and not `Foo&` (with `-fno-elide-constructors`) as explained in my answer.

Comment: @KillKRT The r-value parameter of `drop` binds to the temporary `Foo` but doesn't move it. The actual move will be performed when you construct an object from your r-value reference parameter. If you think about it, this is similar to `Foo f{5}; auto const& fRef = f`. Here, you're binding reference `fRef` to `f`: you don't copy nor move anything.