# Returning non-copyable non-movable rvalue in simple cases

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, copy-elision

I do not understand, why doesn't copy elision work with the r-values in simple cases? Is there a technical problem having this feature in the C++ standard?

The problem partially had been discussed in the [How does guaranteed copy elision work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work%20thread). Still there is no answer.

Here is an example which works as expected:

```cpp
struct x {
   x(int) {}

   void bar() {}

   x(x&&) = delete;
   x& operator=(x&&) = delete;
};

x foo1()
{
  return x{1};  // Works
}
```

As far as I understand, when you call the `foo1` function, via the invisible parameter (kind of `this`) compiler passes the address to the storage where to construct the variable. That is why it costs nothing to return the value when Copy Elision is applied.

However for some reason that does not work in the case when you construct `x` in the middle of the function:

```cpp
x foo2()
{
  auto r = x{1};
  r.bar();
  return r;     // Does not work
}
```

When you try to compile it, you get an error:

```
g++ -c --std=c++2a 1.cpp 
1.cpp: In function ‘x foo2()’:
1.cpp:19:10: error: use of deleted function ‘x::x(x&&)’
   19 |   return r;
      |          ^
1.cpp:6:9: note: declared here
    6 |         x(x&&) = delete;
      |         ^
```

From my point of view in this particular case compiler still can construct the `x` object in the storage provided and return it exactly as in `foo1` case.

Moreover, in case if you enable `x` move ctor, compiler does not call it at all when `foo2` is invoked. Named RVO (NRVO) they call it. :)

I totally understand why it does not work in the following case:

```cpp
x foo3()
{
  auto r1 = x{1};
  auto r2 = x{2};

  return condition ? r1 : r2;
}
```

In the code above there are two objects created and in order to return one, `move` must be applied. In case of one variable... that is not clear for me.

BTW, in case if someone is interested, there is a workaround which might work in some cases:

```cpp
struct y: x
{
   y(int i)
      : x(i)
   {
      bar();
   }
};

y foo3()
{
  return y{1}; // instead of x, we return `y` and all the job is done inside the `y` ctor
}
```

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) even with the compiler providing NRVO the copy or move constructor must still be accessible.  Since they've been deleted, they are not accessible.

Comment: Only prvalues have special semantics.  NRVO does not remove the requirement for a type to be copyable or movable.

Comment: @Eljay: Right. The question is why does it work like that? Is there a reason it cannot be implemented in C++ Standard as Copy Elision?

Comment: I mean I really want this feature in the factory function where I return just one object.

Comment: Originally, all copy elision worked like this - the object had to be copyable. If the elision is optional, we must be assured that the code works for all compilers, even if it is not elided. Then there was an exception specifically made for the first case - elision mandatory. Then there is no requirement to check for copy/move constructors, because they are *never* used.

Comment: *"I really want this feature in the factory function where I return just one object."* - Make a private move c'tor, assuming the factory has access to private members. The object is still not moveable as defined by any trait, but you can leverage NRVO.

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko There was a proposal [P2025](https://github.com/Anton3/cpp-proposals/blob/master/README.md) to add NRVO to mandatory copy elision in C++23, but it seems to have died, it wasn't worked on since 2021. Related Github issue: https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/756

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah, I though about this workaround too. The only issue  so far is it cannot be used if you are not an owner of the non-moveable class. E.g. you cannot modify it. Also it does not work in case if object cannot be moved (if it contains mutexes, atomics) or the thread is started with the pointer to data member allocated inside the class (not heap)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Interesting... 10 votes are strongly against and 8 are against. While in the previous poll there was completely opposite.