How should I take these arguments to ensure return value optimisation?
I want to mimic how Rust does error handling in C++, and I know that using std::move can inhibit RVO, and possibly (I'm not sure) using r-value references. I was wondering in the following how I should take the constructor arguments to the Result class:
enum ResultEnum : unsigned char { Ok, Err };


template <typename T, typename E = bool>
struct Result
{
private:
    ResultEnum result;
public:
    Result(ResultEnum result, const T& t) /* SHOULD I TAKE THE ARGUMENT BY COPY, REFERENCE OR FORWARDING/UNIVERSAL REFERENCE */
    {
        this->t = t; /* WHAT WOULD BE BEST HERE? std::move???*/
        this->result = result;
    }
    Result(ResultEnum result, const E& err) /* SAME HERE, COPY, REF OR FORWARDING/UNIVERSAL REF? */
    {
        this->e = err; /* WHAT WOULD BE BEST HERE? std::move??? Will std::move prevent RVO?*/

        this->result = result;
    }
    union
    {
        T t;
        E e;
    };

    bool is_ok() const{ return result == ResultEnum::Ok; }
    bool is_err() const{ return result == ResultEnum::Err; }

    
};

struct MyFoo {};

Result<MyFoo, bool> createMyFoo()
{
    MyFoo f;
    return { Ok, f }; /* CAN I EXPECT RVO HERE? WHAT EFFECT WOULD CHANGING THE CONSTRUCTOR ARGUMENTS MAKE, IE., COPY vs REF vs FORWARDING/UNIVERSAL REF */
}

int main()
{
    auto f = createMyFoo();
    if (f.is_err())
    {
        /* SOMETHING */
    }
}

Inside the constructor, assuming RVO is taking place, can I assume that any assigning inside the constructor is assigning to the return value in the calling stack frame directly?

Alternatively, C++23 std::expected or Boost Outcome's result.

@Eljay Unfortunately it takes forever for new C++ features to be supported.

Considering that C++23 hasn't been officially published yet https://www.iso.org/standard/83626.html it not surprising that it is also not fully implemented.  :-)

No, RVO is not done, C++ Weekly - Ep 421 - You're Using optional, variant, pair, tuple, any, and expected Wrong!

this situation is dire, f has already materialized, whatever you do next will at least create one more Myfoo in order to materialize Result , you need to prevent the materialization of f which means you must have a constructor that takes in Args...args that forwards it to the constructor of Result, this way you don't need to materialize f to construct Result, you can use something like in_place_t (tag dispatch) in order to trigger the correct constructor for Result instead of an enum

I recommend to read the following article: Copy elision.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77848990/returning-non-copyable-non-movable-rvalue-in-simple-cases. It does not solve the issue, but gives you a hint. E.g. there is a https://github.com/Anton3/cpp-proposals/blob/master/README.md proposal and it was never implemented unfortunately

You should have a constructor template that forwards arguments to T's constructors, just like any good little wrapper in the standard library does, and another one that forwards arguments to E's. Naturally, ResultEnum result shoudn't be a function parameter to thosem but rather a non-type template parameter. And no unions. Use std::variant. Or you can basically just use std::variant as is.

@n.m.couldbeanAI "Naturally, ResultEnum result shoudn't be a function parameter to thosem but rather a non-type template parameter." How can it be a template parameter? Result has to be in either a state of Ok or Err and assignable to something that doesn't know yet whether it's Ok or Err.

"How can it be a template parameter" You declare a template and specialize it differently for Ok and Err. "and assignable" Not relevant, the copy assignment operator should not be such a template, just a plain normal copy assignment. Likewise for move assignment and copy/move constructors. Look at the constructors of std::expected (it uses a normal function parameter tag to differentiate between an answer and an error: one has the tag and the other one does not; you can do the same instead of using ResultEnum).

@n.m.couldbeanAI Do you mean specialise the constructors of Result, so one takes ResultEnum::Ok and the other takes ResultEnum::Err?

"Do you mean specialise the constructors of Result, so one takes ResultEnum::Ok and the other takes ResultEnum::Err" Yes exactly.

I'm getting a but confused. The RVO that you're expecting is the return from createMyFoo? But the parameters you're talking about are to a different function/constructor? It seems like you are conflating two independent optimization points.

@JaMiT Yes, either way the compiler actually RVOs the actual return type, I was trying to avoid the moving of the type contained within the result type. I don't think it matters that much to move it, but in principle I was trying to avoid it.

I've taken some of the comments together to provide an example. I do agree that std::expected or for now boost's result type would be the better choice in production code, but there's certainly no harm in exploring C++ for yourself! So, in the interest of education, I'll also try to explain how std::expected does it and why it actually has 22 constructors rather than just two.
For starters, here is a simple implementation based on your example, but using std::variant:
template<typename T, typename E = bool>
struct Result
{
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr Result(Args&&... args) requires std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
        : result{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {}
    
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr Result(Args&&... args) requires std::constructible_from<E, Args...>
        : result{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {}

    std::variant<T, E> result;

    constexpr bool is_ok() const { return std::holds_alternative<T>(result); }
    constexpr bool is_err() const { return std::holds_alternative<E>(result); }
};

Using this code, you can simply return f; from your function and observe that the Result(MyFoo&&) constructor is selected: f is moved into the result member.
While that's nice to have, this definition is not very well-behaved: the two constructor templates may be ambiguous if no arguments are present so, for example, you can't call Result<MyFoo, bool>{}. As remarked in the comments, the standard library disambiguates this using tag types rather than enum values, in this case both std::in_place_t and std::unexpect_t:
// constructs T from args
template< class... Args >
constexpr explicit expected( std::in_place_t, Args&&... args );

// constructs E from args
template< class... Args >
constexpr explicit expected( std::unexpect_t, Args&&... args );

While these allow you to construct either type directly in place with or without arguments, it would still be nice to support the return f; syntax from before. With std::expected, an expected value can be converted implicitly, while an unexpected value must be returned explicitly as std::unexpected<E>:
template< class U = T >
constexpr explicit(!std::is_convertible_v<U, T>) expected( U&& v );

template< class G >
constexpr explicit(!std::is_convertible_v<const G&, E>)
    expected( const std::unexpected<G>& e );

template< class G >
constexpr explicit(!std::is_convertible_v<G, E>)
    expected( std::unexpected<G>&& e );

Some extra trickery is involved here to allow the use of compatible types other than T and E, as well as the forwarding reference U&&. The unexpected type needs two constructors since a forwarding reference is not possible.
Note that this covers just the most relevant constructors, and that their actual definitions are more complicated, because various prosaic constraints are required to ensure a well-defined overload set without ambiguities. Finally, there is also a partial specialisation for T = void that behaves more like a std::optional<E> instead.
In summary: the easiest way of supporting both copy and move semantics is using forwarding references and std::forward. This is not normally possible in constructors, but can be achieved with constructor templates. In other cases you'll need to provide separate definitions for copying from const&s and moving from &&s.
As for RVO, the rule since C++11 is that for example f in the statement return f; is "move-eligible". It's important that the expression returned is just f or (f), but otherwise if there is a move constructor for the return type, it will be selected.
And to answer the final bit of your question: there is no return value in a constructor and a reference to const cannot be moved from, so as you wrote them they would just copy their arguments. But you should initialise members directly using the colon notation wherever possible.
