Is there any way (compiler extensions or otherwise) to emulate named return value optimisation (NRVO)?
In C++, named return value optimisation (NRVO) refers to the fact that the following code might not call the move constructor of MyContainer:
MyContainer f() {
    MyContainer tmp = g();
    tmp.push_back(h());
    return tmp;
}

The compiler is able to achieve this by constructing tmp in the space specified by the caller for the return value.  (The ABI of such a function is effectively equivalent to f taking in a pointer to a buffer that it will construct the MyContainer into.)
However, this is an optional compiler optimisation, meaning that the compiler is free to not make this optimisation.
Is there a way to force NRVO through some compiler extension or non-standard code?  In other words, I am looking for code that compiles to something more or less equivalent to NRVO-optimised code, except that it should be guaranteed (i.e. not an optional optimisation), and if possible not require that the type is move-constructible.  I am not concerned about how the body of f will look, and I am fine with compiler extensions, so something like either of the two snippets of code below is acceptable:
MyContainer f() {
    __attribute__((must_nrvo)) MyContainer tmp = g();
    tmp.push_back(h());
    return tmp;
}

MyContainer f() {
    void* buf = __magic::get_return_address();
    MyContainer* tmp = new(buf) MyContainer(g());
    tmp->push_back(h());
    __return_without_value;
}

However, I cannot change the function signature, so rewriting the function in the following way is not allowed:
void f(void* buf) {
    MyContainer* tmp = new(buf) MyContainer(g());
    tmp->push_back(h());
}


do you want this for performance, or because the returned type is not copyable? if it the first, most compilers implement NRVO is my understanding.

I want to implement a template-heavy library that doesn't require the user-provided template parameters to be copyable.

NRVO doesn't change program semantics, If the type is not copyable, it's ill-formed regardless.

I think the return type only need to be moveable, instead of copyable, for the first snippet to compile.

I'm aware that NRVO doesn't change program semantics; my question is about rewriting the body of the function in a way that avoids a move (and ideally, permitting non-movable types).

You are contradicting yourself. NRVO does not change program semantics, period. You say you understand that yet you also say you wish to use NRVO to allow a larger set of classes. How does that work?

On the other front, being better than the compiler at when to use NRVO as an optimization seems quite difficult, and there's no hint at why you'd need that in your question. In fact, there are situations where NRVO is impossible, what do you expect should happen then?

There even was a relevant proposal, but it doesn't seem to be "alive" now: open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2025r2. A relevant question to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77848990/580083.

If you have a compiler that doesn't do simple optimizations like this, what are the odds that it will optimize anything else properly? So why bother putting makeup on the pig?

I think a more meaningful question would be: What are the requirements of mainstream compilers to make NRVO happen? If the compiler doesn't do it, there certainly isn't an attribute to force it. But there are ways to encourage it, such as always returning the same named object in all return statements of the function

@BoP I think the OP's motivation is to enable having a non-movable return type. This is not about optimizations.

I second Daniel. The question is an interesting one, but the way it is formulated currently is a bit confusing.

When I was faced with a similar situation, and we were not allowed to change the function signatures, we changed the function return types from Foo (which was non-copyable/non-movable) to std::unique_ptr<Foo>.

Do you have a particular compiler in mind? It's tough to give a negative answer to this sort of question without a limitation on which compiler. (What if someone writes a compiler in response to this question for the sole purpose of implementing such an extension?) Is it enough to consider gcc, clang, and MSVC? Rationale: There's no downside to NRVO that I'm aware of, so it seems more likely that a compiler would provide an extension to disable NRVO rather than force it (that is, it seems to me a compiler would always do the optimization when allowed).

I am invested in (N)RVO in the context of auto because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469786/disallow-the-use-of-auto-for-a-given-class-c14-vs-c17-update

@JaMiT, GCC has -fno-elide-constructors, but I don’t know if it works with -std=c++17.  IMO, a natural way to disable NRVO is if a class has explicit move and copy constructor.  it sadly it is not the case.

I've edited the question to clarify that what I'm looking for is code that will generate assembly that is more or less equivalent to a compiler that does NRVO, except that it is guaranteed and ideally should not require the type to be move constructible. @DanielLangr is correct that this is not about optimisations.

For the purposes of the question, we can limit compilers to GCC, Clang, and MSVC.

On one comment u say "...is correct that this is not about optimisations", on the question u say "I am looking for code that compiles to something [...] ". This is a contradiction, if you want to get specific machine code, then the question is about optimization (regardless of what your are trying to optimize). Given this contradiction, I can offer this that "guarantees" RVO for the point of view of the f function. https://godbolt.org/z/K47objadx . This just kicks the can of course, but if you can explain to us what is wrong about this, maybe we can understand what you are looking for.

This question is about optimisation as much as guaranteed copy elision is about optimisation.  I think we have a different definition of "optimisation" here, and your definition is different from the implied definition in Daniel's comment.  The problems with your code are that (1) there is no guarantee that MyContainer won't be moved, and less importantly (2) MyContainer needs to have a move constructor defined.  Whether f does the potential move within its own body or within a lambda that it calls is immaterial, because the lambda is an implementation detail of f invisible to callers.

Thanks @Bernard, I interpret that your question is about semantics then, you want to return an instance of an unmovable uncopyable type. I recommend you make the example in your question on an archetypical unmovable uncopyable concrete type. I have to check, but I think your class has to have a copy or a move constructor for it to work at all, whether the compiler does NRVO or not.
